# MAX30102 not working?

Tags: esp8266, hardware

I have a project to find the pulse oximetry rate. I used MAX30102 and ESP8266 as shown in the first picture.

### Wiring

```
GND ------> GND
VIN ------> 3.3V
SDA ------> D2
SCL ------> D1
```

[image: Wiring Diagram]
[image: Module Picture]
[image: Wiring Picture]

### Code

I also used the following code in esp2866 programming:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include "spo2_algorithm.h"

MAX30105 particleSensor;

#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255

uint32_t irBuffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t redBuffer[100];  //red LED sensor data


int32_t bufferLength; //data length
int32_t spo2; //SPO2 value
int8_t validSPO2; //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t heartRate; //heart rate value
int8_t validHeartRate; //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200); // initialize serial communication at 115200 bits per second:


  // Initialize sensor
  if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)) //Use default I2C port, 400kHz speed
  {
    Serial.println(F("MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power."));
    while (1);
  }

  Serial.println(F("Attach sensor to finger with rubber band. Press any key to start conversion"));
  while (Serial.available() == 0) ; //wait until user presses a key
  Serial.read();

  byte ledBrightness = 60; //Options: 0=Off to 255=50mA
  byte sampleAverage = 4; //Options: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32
  byte ledMode = 2; //Options: 1 = Red only, 2 = Red + IR, 3 = Red + IR + Green
  byte sampleRate = 100; //Options: 50, 100, 200, 400, 800, 1000, 1600, 3200
  int pulseWidth = 411; //Options: 69, 118, 215, 411
  int adcRange = 4096; //Options: 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384

  particleSensor.setup(ledBrightness, sampleAverage, ledMode, sampleRate, pulseWidth, adcRange); //Configure sensor with these settings
}

void loop()
{
  bufferLength = 100; //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps

  //read the first 100 samples, and determine the signal range
  for (byte i = 0 ; i < bufferLength ; i++)
  {
    while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
      particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data

    redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
    irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
    particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

    Serial.print(F("red="));
    Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(F(", ir="));
    Serial.println(irBuffer[i], DEC);
  }

  //calculate heart rate and SpO2 after first 100 samples (first 4 seconds of samples)
  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);

  //Continuously taking samples from MAX30102.  Heart rate and SpO2 are calculated every 1 second
  while (1)
  {
    //dumping the first 25 sets of samples in the memory and shift the last 75 sets of samples to the top
    for (byte i = 25; i < 100; i++)
    {
      redBuffer[i - 25] = redBuffer[i];
      irBuffer[i - 25] = irBuffer[i];
    }

    //take 25 sets of samples before calculating the heart rate.
    for (byte i = 75; i < 100; i++)
    {
      while (particleSensor.available() == false) //do we have new data?
        particleSensor.check(); //Check the sensor for new data


      redBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getRed();
      irBuffer[i] = particleSensor.getIR();
      particleSensor.nextSample(); //We're finished with this sample so move to next sample

      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(redBuffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(irBuffer[i], DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(heartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(validHeartRate, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(spo2, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2Valid="));
      Serial.println(validSPO2, DEC);
    }

    //After gathering 25 new samples recalculate HR and SP02
    maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(irBuffer, bufferLength, redBuffer, &spo2, &validSPO2, &heartRate, &validHeartRate);
  }
}
```

### Error

When executing, it showed me in the window that:

```
11:48:31.564 -> MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power.
```

I have used two of the max30102, but it shows the same result.
The MAX30102 does not turn on and the light also doesn't work. Are there any solutions?

Comment: The text and the wiring image show two different connections: The first with SDA to pin D1 and SCL to pin D2, while the image shows them swapped. What do you actually have on your hardware?

Comment: Yeah sorry ,I made a mistake , SDA ---->D2    SCL----->D1  I will adjust it.

Comment: Can you please try the [I2C Scanner sketch](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/) and see if there are any devices reported on the I2C bus? It just checks at what addresses there are devices that actually answer on the bus.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the reply, . I tried it, but after executing it shows me a window that  "No I2C devices found".

Comment: please post a clear, well lit, in focus picture of the wiring

Comment: @jsotola ok i added another picture

Comment: @chrisl I try agagin the I2C scanner after removed resistors now it display "i2c device found at address 0x57 done " but the led not lit

Comment: Before someone pulls the trigger on closing this, please note that they'd added the wiring image requested. It just wasn't displaying owing to a markdown problem (now corrected).

Comment: Alright, no one else is going to say it, so I will: You have `particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST)`.   Switch this to `I2C_SPEED_STANDARD` and see if it makes a difference and use the configuration you'd seen return 0x57 in the scanner.